# chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-495106134 line

Tags: android

I am getting the chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-495106134 for samsung modals n android version 12.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377 : Current process com.briox.riversip.android.asports.baseball (pid 32342), lock owner unknown
```

Comment: I am getting this due to admob